# in Batch:keep functions in the file they are used in, or keep functions in function-specific files

Tags: function, batch-file, console-application

About a week ago I started making a small batch text/turn-based rpg.

Currently what I'm doing is putting all the functions that are used in a file in that file, i.e I have a file named 'Init.bat' I put all the display/logic/arithmetic/validation/variable-functions in it. What I'm wondering is.. would it be better to put the functions in their own file, i.e file for display/logic/etc, or continue what I'm doing now?

The only files that are 'working' are: Classes.bat,Init.bat,PlayerInfo.bat

https://github.com/Ravkrat/batchrpg/tree/fixingInit <-latest build

(hopefully its ok for me to link to GitHub.. the batch file is large now and don't want to make this post to long)

TL;DR

separate functions from the file they are used in and put them in function specific files,or keep functions in the file that uses them.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference, really.

Comment: true that, think i'll keep on doing what I was doing